# What is the initial password of MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

I downloaded MySQL server 5.7 on my computer (first time) to prove it. But the installer asking me for a password for root@localHost that I have no idea where it is.

I saw a page that you can reset the password using the command line, but the command line ask me too for a password.

What I can do?

1. UPDATE: 
   You have told me that if I have not set a password , then the server does not require you to enter one, but observe ! I want to configure the program but will not let me continue !

[image]

2. UPDATE (SOLVED): had to reinstall the MySQL server and the problem disappeared ... (Still asking why happened that...)

[image]

Thank you all for your responses and comments!

Answer (score 1):

I think that by default there is no password set for root account. 
[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

> If you have never assigned a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root.

Answer (score 1):

Your default account for the connection to the service of phpmyadmin is user: root and no password. That exist for the Security of the databases